# filter, sort and search through array by selectors in redux toolkit (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

My app fetches array of products on mounting (array length < 10, so I fetch everything) and saves in redux store. `Home` page has filter buttons, sorting (price, weight, etc) and search (all this settings are also stored as store slice). How am I supposed to filter + sort + search simultaneously before rendering? As I understand I should use 3 selectors and pass corresponding setting in it (filter by, sort by and search text), but how to combine into one final result arr? Also I want to use reselect to memoize. Previously this logic was stored in `Home.tsx` component and looked like this:

```js
const sortedItems = useMemo(
  () => items.sort((a, b) => b[sorting] - a[sorting]),
  [items, sorting]
);

const filteredItems = sortedItems
  .filter((item) => (filterBy !== "all" ? item.category === filterBy : true))
  .filter(
    (item) =>
      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      item.category.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      item.ingredients.some((ing) => ing.toLowerCase().includes(search))
  );
```

I created one selector inside slice file:

```js
const selectItems = (state: RootState) => state.product.items;

export const selectBy = (
  filterBy: CategoriesType,
  sorting: SortType,
  search: string
) =>
  createSelector(selectItems, (items) =>
    items
      .filter((item) =>
        filterBy !== "all" ? item.category === filterBy : true
      )
      .sort((a, b) => b[sorting] - a[sorting])
      .filter(
        (item) =>
          item.title.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          item.category.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
          item.ingredients.some((ing) => ing.toLowerCase().includes(search))
      )
  );
```

And inside components I pass params to it:

```js
const items = useAppSelector(selectBy(filterBy, sorting, search));
```

But I don't know if it is right approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use reselect selector with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291084/use-reselect-selector-with-parameters)

Comment: @DrewReese not really, let's rephrase my question: What is right aproach in multistep selection: one selector with huge logic inside (like the one i created above) or 3-4 createSelectors, each one using previous one as input?

Comment: Unfortunately I think that's a bit too subjective for stackoverflow. You are only selecting one "chunk" of state, so I don't see how you would need more than one selector function.

Comment: @DrewReese i have similar thoughts, thanks for your help